# Integration with SSIS

Tags: ssis, netsuite

I know SSIS is an ETL tool. that is based on SQL Server.

Can I use it without using the SQL Server data?

I want to integrate 2 applications

Can I use APIs of one application to extract data then Transform this data then Load it into another application (NetSuite)

No reading or writing in SQL Server needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create packages that do not connect to or access a SQL Server. However, you do need SQL Server installed to be able to run SSIS packages.

SSIS doesn't include a native NetSuite connector. While several third-parties offer connectors for NetSuite, these are not free and require a license to use in a production environment.